# How to use browser solidity as replacement for the mix-ide?

Tags: remix

As mix will not be developed further and browser-solidity should be a replacement for it, I have tried to use browser-solidity as chrome extension.

Now I have some questions about it.

- How do I point to local sol files in my file-system? Is it even possible?
- How do I test my frontend files (html/js)?

Both where possible with mix, and if browser-solidity want to replace the mix-ide it should support these use-cases.

Should I open a feature request?

Comment: I don't think browsers solidity wants to replace mist. It's primarily an online compiler, not an IDE, even though IDE-like features have been added due to popular requests.

Comment: he is talking about MIX not mist

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, browser-solidity isn't really a replacement for mix. What you can do (and I myself do) is make your own development environment with existing (and much more powerful) IDEs.

For example, I use:

- EMACS with solidity-mode to write all my code.
- gulp to automate a large number of tasks, including compilation.
- [beefy](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy) to host my frontend.
- [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to simulate a blockchain.
- mocha for test driven development.

And a handful of other minor tools. You could switch out nearly any part of this, depending on choice. (vi has highlighting for solidity, for instance.)

However, if this isn't your cup of tea, ether.camp has a browser-based Etherum-integrated IDE. (I'm not sure where to find it on their site at the moment, but I know it exists) I believe Visual Studio also has a first-party Ethereum plugin.