# How to change the compiler the mix-ide uses?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mix, solc

I have build the mix-ide from source, is there a way to change the solidity compiler it uses? I have tried to simply replace the solidity folder in the webumbrella directory with a new version but with no luck.

Is there a compile switch for it, or something similar?

Comment: It's probably better to avoid Mix-ide all together.  It was never completed and is a dropped project which remains buggy.  Better to use Browser Solidity as a chrome extension coupled with TestRPC for development work.

Comment: I know, but also it is the only ide providing local files and some front end testing. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10596/how-to-use-browser-solidity-as-replacement-for-the-mix-ide there seems to be no alternative. For testing I use Junit. (https://github.com/UrsZeidler/uml2solidity/wiki/TestWithJava)

Comment: Hooking through testRPC allows for front-end testing.  Though yes, it would be nice if Browser Solidity had a save to local function.

Comment: Not only save to local, but load from local, normally you want your files in a repo and have them checked out. The browser solidity cannot be used in this way, from what I know. So it also cannot resolve imports, when the files are local. These are essential features for an ide.